# Drop duplicates but keep max value and keep first row where max value is 0 if there is no max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, max

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'], 'Title': ["CEO", "VP", "CEO", "VP", "Exec Director", "Director", "Manager"], 'Compensation': ['125000', '100000', '0', '0','0','0','0'] })
```

My goal is to drop duplicate values according to index and keep the max value under compensation for that index number. However, there are indices where all compensation values are 0. In those cases, I just want to keep the first listed person as it is usually the CEO.

I've tried the following solutions:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Index', as_index=False).max('Compensation')
```

This does not work for me because for the index groupings where there is 0 compensation, it seems to choose the last one instead of the first

I've also tried:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Compensation', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Index', keep='first').sort_index()
```

This does not work for me because it does not always take the first listed person in the index where the entire group reports 0 compensation. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. I can't find a pattern or reason why this is the case. I realize that the problem does not seem to replicate in my sample dataframe

A potential constraint in the solution is that my DF is approx 20 million rows and the resulting DF2 should be about 1.6 million rows. The codes above are successful in achieving that much but again, the problem is how the 0 compensation index groups are getting pulled.

I understand the documentation states that the first encountered should be taken but this is not the case given I have inspected the data before and after using the codes above.

Any ideas about how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Let us try `idxmax`

```
#df.Compensation=df.Compensation.astype(int)
out = df.loc[df.groupby('Index')['Compensation'].idxmax()]
Out[321]: 
  Index Title  Compensation
0     0   CEO        125000
2     1   CEO             0
```

Update the reason here is `sort_values` default is `quicksort`, we should change to `mergesort`

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Compensation', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Index', keep='first',kind = 'mergesort').sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you so much BENY! I made 1 small adjustment to your code and it worked as intended.  I moved the argument for kind to sort_values so the code is: `df2 = df.sort_values('Compensation', kind= 'mergesort', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Index', keep='first').sort_index()`